# get_posts for ACF return nothing

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Trying to get posts by ACF fields query:

- ACF field «true / false» key = key1 / name = name1 / value = «on».
- ACF field «radio» key = key2 / name = name2 / values

  - a : 'Point a' /
  - b : 'Point b’

Of course, posts with these fields / values exist.

What’s wrong?

```php
$result = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => $key1, // or name1 - result the same

    'meta_value' => 'on'
)); // return nothing


$result = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => $key2, // or name2 - result the same
    'meta_value' => 'a'
)); // return nothing
```

Comment: Fix your single quotes and check again? `‘meta_key’` should be `'meta_key'` and so on.

Comment: It’s just because of manual input of this code. Originally all items have single quotes.
Sample:
$query = array(
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_key' => 'field_5c8a5c5f991b0',
   'meta_value' => 'on'
  );
  $posts = get_posts($query);

Comment: Your meta value is return Boolean type?(true / false)

Comment: Replace ‘on’ with true for true_false field - the same result. Nothing

Comment: Just answer my question brother in yes or no.
Your meta value is return Boolean type?(true / false

Answer (score 0):

See my last comment.
Maybe last sentence about ACF checkbox will helpful